# Optimize sed string

Tags: regex, linux, sed, dns

I need to modify /etc/resolv.conf file with backup before modifying. This file contents such strings:

```
nameserver 10.99.201.11
nameserver 10.77.201.11
nameserver 10.99.201.10
nameserver 10.77.201.12
```

Desired result

```
nameserver 10.99.201.11
nameserver 10.200.65.11
nameserver 10.99.201.10
nameserver 10.200.65.12
```

Conditions of modify which I thought up:

```
if some string starts with "nameserver" word
AND
if that string ends on "11" or "12"
THEN
replace 10.77.201 to 10.200.65
```

This sed command works perfect

```
sed '-i.orig' -e '/^nameserver/s/10.77.201.11/10.200.65.11/; /^nameserver/s/10.77.201.12/10.200.65.12/' /etc/resolv.conf
```

but I need to optimize it to one sed pass. This gonna be with regexp pattern but I am weak with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found solution by myself

```
sed '-i.orig' -E '/^nameserver.*(11)|(12)$/s/10.77.201/10.200.65/' /etc/resolv.conf
```

better one

```
sed '-i.orig' 's/\<10\>\.77\.201\.1\([12]\)/10.200.65.1\1/' /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(tested with GNU `sed`).

```
sed -E '/^nameserver/s/(your_11_one)|(your_12_one)/your_new_value/' Input_file
```

Add `-i.bak` to take backup of Input_file and save output into Input_file itself.

OR

```
sed -E '/^nameserver.*(11)|(12)$/s/old_ip/new_ip/' Input_file
```